Is there a way to get environment variable from command line in gauge
I am running gauge tests on jenkins job by running following command :
mvn gauge:execute

It works fine but we have a requirement to run gauge for every feature branch environment, here I need to pass this environment name as a command line argument when I am executing gauge command, something like this
mvn gauge:execute -Denvname=QA

But this is working, i and maven gauge plugin and added environmentvariables config there, but that also not working plae help me pass the envname to my java step implementation.

Try this:
String envName = System.getProperty("envname");
